# How can I listen for an event based on a common class/ object name instead of a unique layer in Framer JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, framerjs

I would like to return the unique name of the object that the user has clicked on but I can't find the solution. Below is what I'm trying to achieve but in CoffeeScript.

```
$(".class").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked on this specific element");
});
```

The best example I could find is shown below, but each layer is unique so they can't be assigned to different layers.

```
layerA.on Events.Click, (event, layer) ->
    print "This layer was clicked", layer.name
```

I can listen to the event on each layer individually, but that would breach the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out myself. Here's the solution below.

Create an array and store all of the layer names inside

```
layerArray = [layer, layer2, layer3, layer4]
```

Create a function that will be called when the click event is triggered, passing in the layer object and the layer index

```
callFunc = (layer, index) ->
    print index
```

Loop over each layer in the array and pass the clicked layer to the function

```
for layer, index in layerArray
    layer.on(Events.Click, callFunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".class").click(function(e){
    alert(e.target); // The DOM element that fired this event.
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler specifically

> .click( handler )
>   handler Type: Function( Event eventObject )
>   A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

And http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

> event.target
>   The DOM element that initiated the event.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your answer. I managed to figure it out myself earlier and i ended up writing an answer for others to see, just in case they had the same issue. It's a Framer.js question and it uses coffeescript. I'm new to it myself and realised that I had to loop over the array values to get the specific index that was clicked. jQuery does it slightly differently. Anyways, thanks again for your help!